# It sometimes plays videos with HLS. For example, it plays for 3 hours. It doesn't play videos for 10 hours

Tags: php, http-live-streaming

I made a video bot with PHP. It plays videos in 3gp.

`<source src='<?php echo $mp4_link; ?>' type='application/x-mpegURL'/>` => It sometimes plays videos with HLS. For example, it plays for 3 hours. It doesn't play videos for 10 hours.

`<source src='<?php echo $mp4_link; ?>' type='video/mp4'/>` => When it is set to Mp4, it plays low quality videos all the time.

```
    <video id='hls-video'>
<source src='<?php echo $mp4_link; ?>' type='application/x-mpegURL'/>
```

The reason for this is not related to fluid player, I think. I have tried other players.All players are the same. HLS videos play for 3 hours. It does not play for 20 hours.

Comment: Seems like a client side issue, not PHP. Anything in developer console at 3 hours when video stops?

Comment: I'm getting videos from a big site.It sometimes plays videos with HLS. Sometimes it doesn't play.But it plays videos 3gp. low quality. Now the videos are not working at all. But few hour later works automatically.

Comment: Please edit the question and include the code. We can't read code in comments. Also please give more details. In the question it sounded like you were playing a +3 hour video and it cuts out at the 3 hour mark with HLS playback. Last comment sounds like it plays sporadically depending on when you visit.

Comment: I now use vds Centos 7, the version of the site is Php 5.6. I guess it has nothing to do with them. I play videos with HLS. It sometimes plays videos. Sometimes it does not play, it gets random these days. It happens often. Sometimes it plays 10 minutes, not after 10 minutes. The traffic of my site is around 2k. Maybe they are ban My server IP? but if they are Ban my server ip, then why sometimes playing. But it's playing when i do it low quality 3gp.

Comment: The request for the video would come from your home network, not server. Could have a rate limit on requests from one IP in X minutes. Check developer console it should show something in the network tab.

Comment: I did not fully understand what you said. I'm getting videos from a very large site. There is HLS support. Videos open on that site, sometimes open on my own site, sometimes not. I couldn't solve this problem.

Comment: `<source src=` makes a request from the client loading the HTML, not the server. If the site you are using offers support you'll probably get a faster and more accurate support there. If they limit an IP to ten loads a minute and you are refreshing every few seconds you'd get blocked for some duration. Again though this would display in the developer console.

Comment: Specified “type” attribute of “application/x-mpegURL” is not supported. Load of media resource https://vid4-l3.cdn.com/videos/3gp/a/3/c/s.com_a3c60913d18890139f4df80b58c65dea.mp4?e=1594743265&ri=1024&rs=85&h=21b12e0e4808165970bbb7ab1b6f8add failed. But sometimes it opens videos. Sometimes it does so.

Comment: So if I put a proxy on my player, will the problem be solved?

Comment: Specified “type” attribute of “application/x-mpegURL” is not supported. Load of media resource.